# Parsing relative links on a html page

Tags: html, parsing

I'm trying to parse a page to find all valid urls, but here is a problem. There are 3 types of links on a page: url (_http://site.com/dir/page.html), absolute uri (/dir/page.html) and relative uri (dir/page.html without starting slash). Probably i'm wrong about terminology, i'm not an html coder. But that's not the case in any way.
I need to find and collect all urls (i.e. _http://site.com/dir/subdir/page.html and so on). And here is the problem. If there is a page _http://site.com/dir/page.html with a link like <a href="subdir/page.html">link</a> it's supposed to bring us to _http://site.com/dir/subdir/page.html. But if there is <base href="/"> in the head section of a page, same link leads to _http://site.com/subdir/page.html i.e. different from _http://site.com/dir/subdir/page.html.
The question is if there can be anything else in html code on a page that can influence target url.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML as such there is nothing else beside the href base You mentioned

What could become tricky and should be considered is that there might be linkage on page made by script execution, so things like window.location.href = something. This would be easy if the links are clearly stated, but they might be also computed by the script and then You could miss the link or mis-read it by using simple parsing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really considered about client-side generated code, only pure text/html response body :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually how url linking in html works, please read: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3 .  So say you're in /admin/ and you need /admin/login.aspx .  My relative URL is login.aspx, while my absolute is /admin/login.aspx make sense?

So basically what I'm saying is consider which directory your link is being served out of.  That will determine the type and content of the url link to use.

Other than that, as stated already, jscript and server side code can also do linking.